# User input choice using while loops and if loops in python

Tags: python, validation, loops, while-loop, sqlite

I am new to Python so this is probably something pretty basic. I have found similar questions on Stackoverflow and other places but not exactly the same.

I am trying to write a Python program to update an Sqlite database. The database has three columns, item, quantity, price. Previously I had updated the database by inserting these values for each of these columns into my code, but now I want to do the same thing using user input.

I hope you'll see from my code that I have created 3 functions to create a table, insert data into the table and one to view the data present in the table.

Using a variable `user_choice` I then ask the user what they want to do with the program. 
I attempt to handle errors firstly by converting the input to a string, secondly to change it lower-case, and thirdly with the use of a while loop. The while loop should loop if the input is not either i or v, or if the input is validated the condition should be satisfied to exit the loop.

The problem is occurring at the while loop I believe. The variable is never validated and it always enters the while loop and stays there. Even then though, each time it loops there is a chance for the variable `user_choice` to be changed, but again it never gets validated.

Could somebody tell me what's going wrong with this? I am keen to learn.

```
import sqlite3

def create_table():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store (item TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def insert_data(item, quantity, price):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO store VALUES (?,?,?)",(item, quantity, price))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def view_data():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM store")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

create_table()

user_choice=str(input("What would you like to do? \n Insert data (I) \n View data (V) \n Enter your choice, I or V:  "))
user_choice=user_choice.lower
print(user_choice)

while user_choice not in ['i','v']:
    print ("Your choice is invalid. Please try again.")
    user_choice=input("Choose I or V:  ")
    user_choice=user_choice.lower

if user_choice == 'i':
    user_input = input("Enter the item, quantity and price you want to update: ")
    input_list = user_input.split(',')
    item=str(input_list[0])
    quantity=int(input_list[1])
    price=float(input_list[2])
    insert_data(item,quantity,price)
elif user_choice == 'v':
    print(view_data())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made an easily fixable mistake :). All you have to do is change this line:

```
user_choice=user_choice.lower
```

To this one:

```
user_choice=user_choice.lower()
```

This line occurs twice, once outside your while loop and once inside, so make sure you change both. The problem was, you weren’t calling the `lower()` function because you didn’t have the parentheses at the end.

Comment: Thank you! Apparently I  can't upvote yet, but take my thanks instead.

Comment: Always glad to help!